# Schema evolution with nested types and case classes in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We are storing our data in parquet. We read it into a dataframe and convert to case classes.
Here's a mock example:

```
sqlContext.read.parquet(path)
      .as[House]
```

House is a complex type with nested case classes:

```
case class House(rooms: Seq[Room])
case class Room(area: Int)
```

Our problem is that we want to modify a field in Room:

```
case class Room(width: Int, length: Int)
```

We have logic for converting area to width and length.

**What is the recommended way of reading both the old schema and the new schema with the same code?**

We are thinking of using parquet's merge schema while reading, inspect the resulting Dataframe to migrate the properties, then convert to our case classes. This doesn't seem to be possible with nested types like this.